# Require In-App Purchase

Tags: ios, iphone, in-app-purchase, appstore-approval

I want to create an app that will be displayed as FREE on the App Store, but upon opening it, users are required to do and in-app purchase to be able to access any of the content. I am reading the App Store Review Guidelines, but I am not sure if Apple allows this since the users will not be able to see anything on the app unless they subscribe to it.

The reason I need this is because my client wants the app to be sold at $0.99/year and I don't think this can be done by setting only via Price Tier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a membership only app.

You must sign in to use the app (you can give apple a test account)

then you can manage the membership on your own servers. Or allow them to sign up with the in app purchase.

(enable both the user login and the in app purchase to get a user login, then you can give apple a "test" account that requires no purchase)

They will test your in app purchases anyhow so make sure you follow all the rules on Re-Activating in app purchases, this way if the user comes back and reloads their purchase and they have 2 months left you are sure the app will still allow them.

As long as you dont try to accept credit cards from the app, and use their in app purchase system you should be fine.

If you want to enable users to purchase their account from your server, you cannot allow the purchase from the app. The login however can enable the app without the purchase (and the test account should) but in app purchase should allow them to attach their purchase to the account they use.

I think im rambling now so I hope thats enough clarification.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is present a demo of the app as a feature before the user buying in-app purchase.just a screen extra. So that Apple does not reject it.

The other option is:
If you have a login/password app, you can tell apple that your app requires login before any feature can be given, only if your in-app thing is login related.